# ¿Cómo instancio una clase interna?

Tags: java, clase

Tengo que instanciar un objeto de una clase interior y me funciona bien dentro de la clase pero no fuera.

```
// Fichero Main.java
public class Main {
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Test.Interior interior = new Test.Interior(); // Esta línea falla
        Test.InteriorStatic interiorStatic = new Test.InteriorStatic();
    }
}

// Fichero Test.java
public class Test {

    public class Interior {
    }

    public static class InteriorStatic {

    }

    public void algo()
    {
        Test.Interior interior = new Test.Interior();
    }
}
```

La línea en que indico que falla da el siguiente error de compilación :

> Main.java:15: error: an enclosing instance that contains Test.Interior
>   is required

Pero exáctamente la misma línea dentro de `algo()` sí que funciona bien. Y tanto `Test` como `Test.Interior` son `public`.
Si hago que la clase `Test.Interior` sea `static` no da el error, pero es una clase que no tengo posibilidad de modificar en el código de producción.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Interior` es una clase interna (*inner class*, [JLS, §8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)). Para crear una instancia de la clase interna, debes crear primero una instancia de la clase externa. O más exactamente, debes crear primero la «instancia envolvente inmediata» (*immediately enclosing instance*, [JLS, §15.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2)). Esto es:

```java
Test.Interior interior = new Test().new Interior();
```

Answer (score 4):

al crear la clase anidada, estás indicando que las instancias de Interior dependen de Test. por eso debes crear primero una instancia de Test, y luego crear las instancias de interior.

```
public class Main {
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Test t = new Test();
    Test.Interior interior = t.new Interior();
    Test.InteriorStatic interiorStatic = new Test.InteriorStatic();
}
}
```